# Roots of $p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(x-d_i)+k^2, \ \ \ \ n\in\mathbb N,\ k\in\mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let
$$p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{2n}(x-d_i)+k^2, \ \  \ \ n\in\mathbb N,\ k\in\mathbb R$$
where $d_i>0$ for all $i=1,\dots,2n$. Can I infer that
$$p(x)=0$$
has only roots with positive real part?

Comment: Can you add some context ?

Comment: The letter $i$ is a bad choice of index here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let's show that $x = -1 + i$ can be a root of such a polynomial for a certain choice of $d_j$'s and $k$.

The problem amounts to showing that there are some $2n$ numbers of the form $-1 - d_j + i$ whose product is a negative real number $-k^2$. In the complex plane, this amounts to picking $2n$ numbers on the line $y = 1$ with arguments strictly between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$, whose product is on the negative real axis.

Thus it is sufficient to find $2n = 6$ arguments between $3\pi/4$ and $\pi$ whose sum is equal to $5\pi$. But that is easy.

Comment: In fact, a slight modification of this argument results in a counterexample with $2n = 4$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The problem amounts to showing that there are some $2n$ numbers of the form $-1-d_j+i$ whose product is $-k^2$? EDIT: Never mind I see it now :-)